# How to overlay SRT or ASS on a video and output the pre-render captioned video?

Tags: subtitles, animation-rendering, closed-captioning

I noticed a lot of video having pre-render captions. I remember I saw someone working in a Chinese studio that primarily does translation works and she was using a software to render the SRT or ASS file to raw videos automatically. I thought it was very convenient and wonder if anyone knows how it was done.

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Premiere Pro allows you to create caption files (including SRT) and export them individually (as SRT files) or embedded with the actual video. [This link](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/working-with-captions.html) gives a pretty good overview of how it's done in Premiere.